# Video encoders give inconsistent results

Tags: android, video, encoding

I've successfully encoded a video by generating images and assembling them.

Unfortunately, I've discovered that the results are inconsistent between devices. Some users have weird looking videos, and from what I understand, the used codec makes a difference.

My successful results use the `OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc` codec, and I have bad rendering with `OMX.google.h264.encoder`.

When the failing one is used, I get this log, which I don't have with the other one:

```
> I/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.encoder] cannot encode color aspects. Ignoring.
```

I've looked a bit into color format but I'm pretty much clueless, any hints?

Comment: Encoders is just one part of the problem. There are also different levels (e.g. for bandwidth, and calculation capabilities). not all devices could handle all levels. So, you may check better the other settings of encoder, and you must definitely look on video sites about what are the recommended settings for high end, low-end, etc. devices.

Comment: I ended up using ffmpeg to do the encoding, and more specifically the https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg library